# При SELECT возвращает адрес в памяти

Tags: php, sql, память, firebird

Есть сервер Firebird. Мне необходимо вытащить из него данные. Я использую php. При выполнении запроса:

```
SELECT note 
FROM some_table 
WHERE cdate = '2021-10-20'
```

Мне приходит ответ:

```
["NOTE"]=> string(18) "0x0002c38300000108"
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема именно? Другие запросы проходят нормально. Может ли быть это связано со структурой таблицы?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А нет никакой проблемы. Что в поле записано - то и возвращается.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашёл сам. но вдруг кому ещё понадобится вот ответ:
просто при Select нужно добавить преобразование типа:

```
SELECT CAST (note as VARCHAR(3200))
FROM some_table
WHERE cdate = '2021-10-20'
```

т.к. тип данных note возможно является BLOB.

Работает и этот вариант:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(note FROM 1 FOR 32000) as VARCHAR(32000)) 
FROM some_table 
WHERE data = '2021-10-20'
```

Comment: Как это - `тип данных note возможно является BLOB`? Какой тип вы задали, такой и есть.